# How do I ignore the error MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "cofigmap-volume" : configmaps "configmap" not found

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I've mounted the configmap in my deployment file but conditionally create a configmap through oc create configmap command during deployment. Is there a way I could mount the path in my deployment.yaml but when configmap is not there it can ignore that error and bring up the pods any how.

Comment: I suspect that may only be possible when consuming keys from a config map as environment variables. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-env-vars

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to ConfigMapVolumeSource  and [ValidatingWebhookConfiguration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#configmapvolumesource-v1-core) you
can find optional parameter:

```
Specify whether the ConfigMap or it's keys must be define
```

So please try and add "`optional: true`" in your volumes [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap) properties:

```
volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: special-config
        optional: true
```

Note:

> [Restrictions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#restrictions):
>
> You must create a ConfigMap before referencing it in a Pod specification (**unless you mark the ConfigMap as “optional”**). If you reference a ConfigMap that doesn’t exist, the Pod won’t start. Likewise, references to keys that don’t exist in the ConfigMap will prevent the pod from starting.

Please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Writing  `CRD` and `CRD controller` for your app can solve this. You can deploy the yaml for your `crd`, the controller will check whether there exist a `configmap` or not. Depending on the result, the `controller` will change the `deployment` yaml and deploy it.